# Parsing XML Document in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am writing a C# code to parse the following XML doc :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<teams>
  <team id="1">
    <name>RealMadrid</name>
    <players>
      <player id="1" role="Forward">
        <firstname>Cristiano</firstname>
        <lastname>Ronaldo</lastname>
        <number>7</number>
      </player>
      <player id="2" role="Forward">
        <firstname>Gareth</firstname>
        <lastname>Bale</lastname>
        <number>11</number>
      </player>
      <player id="3" role="Midfield">
        <firstname>Toni</firstname>
        <lastname>Kroos</lastname>
        <number>8</number>
      </player>
      <player id="4" role="Midfield">
        <firstname>Luka</firstname>
        <lastname>Modric</lastname>
        <number>19</number>
      </player>
      <player id="5" role="Defence">
        <firstname>Sergio</firstname>
        <lastname>Ramos</lastname>
        <number>4</number>
      </player>
      <player id="6" role="Defence">
        <firstname>Raphael</firstname>
        <lastname>Varane</lastname>
        <number>2</number>
      </player>
      <player id="7" role="Goalkeeper">
        <firstname>Keylor</firstname>
        <lastname>Navas</lastname>
        <number>1</number>
      </player>
    </players>
  </team>
  
    
    
  <team id="2">
    <name>Barcelona</name>
    <players>
      <player id="1" role="Forward">
        <firstname>Lionel</firstname>
        <lastname>Messi</lastname>
        <number>10</number>
      </player>
      <player id="2" role="Forward">
        <firstname>Neymar</firstname>
        <lastname>Jr.</lastname>
        <number>11</number>
      </player>
      <player id="3" role="Midfield">
        <firstname>Ivan</firstname>
        <lastname>Rakitic</lastname>
        <number>4</number>
      </player>
      <player id="4" role="Midfield">
        <firstname>Andres</firstname>
        <lastname>Iniesta</lastname>
        <number>8</number>
      </player>
      <player id="5" role="Defence">
        <firstname>Gerard</firstname>
        <lastname>Pique</lastname>
        <number>3</number>
      </player>
      <player id="6" role="Defence">
        <firstname>Javier</firstname>
        <lastname>Mascherano</lastname>
        <number>14</number>
      </player>
      <player id="7" role="Goalkeeper">
        <firstname>Andre</firstname>
        <lastname>Ter Stegen</lastname>
        <number>1</number>
      </player>
    </players>
  </team>
  
    
    
      
  <team id="3">
    <name>Liverpool</name>
    <players>
      <player id="1" role="Forward">
        <firstname>Daniel</firstname>
        <lastname>Sturridge</lastname>
        <number>15</number>
      </player>
      <player id="2" role="Forward">
        <firstname>Roberto</firstname>
        <lastname>Firmino</lastname>
        <number>11</number>
      </player>
      <player id="3" role="Midfield">
        <firstname>Philippe</firstname>
        <lastname>Coutinho</lastname>
        <number>10</number>
      </player>
      <player id="4" role="Midfield">
        <firstname>Adam</firstname>
        <lastname>Lallana</lastname>
        <number>20</number>
      </player>
      <player id="5" role="Defence">
        <firstname>Joel</firstname>
        <lastname>Matip</lastname>
        <number>32</number>
      </player>
      <player id="6" role="Defence">
        <firstname>Dejan</firstname>
        <lastname>Lovren</lastname>
        <number>6</number>
      </player>
      <player id="7" role="Goalkeeper">
        <firstname>Simon</firstname>
        <lastname>Mignolet</lastname>
        <number>22</number>
      </player>
    </players>
  </team>
</teams>
```

I want to write the firstname and lastname for players of a specific team.
I wrote the following code :

```
var realTeam = from db in xelement.Elements("team")
                       where (string)db.Element("name")=="RealMadrid"
                       select db;
        //Console.WriteLine("Real Madrid");
        foreach (var e in realTeam)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
```

This code is giving all the xml part related to "RealMadrid".
What should I do write on the firstname and lastname of this part?

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: You're selecting the `name` element. Try `select db.Elements("players");` instead of `select db;` then iterate through the players, each element should be of type `player` which has lastname and firstname.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL I tried your solution and I only got the following message in the Console : System.Xml.Linq.XContainer+<GetElements>d__40

Comment: RoyNasr please mark @feal answers as accepted. if his solution worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
  var xmlContent = "YOUR XML";
  var xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);
  var realTeamName = "RealMadrid";

  var realTeam = from team in xmlDoc.Elements("teams")
                                    .Descendants("team")
                 where team.Element("name").Value == realTeamName
                 select team;

  var players = realTeam.Elements("players").Elements(); // get players
  foreach (var player in players)                        // iterate over players
  {
    Console.WriteLine("First name: " + player.Element("firstname").Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Last name: " + player.Element("lastname").Value);
  }
```

So far you've got the team, but now you need to step into the team elements to get the players list and then the single player with firstname, lastname....

Comment: When I execute this code I get the following exception on  "var xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);" : "System.Xml.XmlException: 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.'"

Comment: did you fill the variable xmlContent with your real xmlContent? Because in this example the xmlContent variable contains "Your Xml" which is of course not valid.

Comment: Yes I wrote like this :  var xmlContent = "..\\..\\XMLFile1.xml"; where my xml file name is : XMLFile1.xml

Comment: Ok there is the error: You need to load the filecontent first: so use var xmlContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("..\\..\\XMLFile1.xml");

Comment: Try `XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); doc.Load("path to your file"); string xmlContent = doc.InnerXml;`.

Comment: I put `XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlContent);
            xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);`

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you're not selecting the `players` element in your statement. Try the following:

```
var realTeam = from db in xelement.Elements("team")
               where (string)db.Element("name")=="RealMadrid"
               select db.Elements("players");
//Console.WriteLine("Real Madrid");
if (realTeam.Count() != 1)
{
    //more than 1 team called RealMadrid was found, handle this case here
    return;
}
foreach (var e in realTeam.Single())
{
    Console.WriteLine("First Name: " + e.Element("firstname").Value);  //or e.Element("firstname").ToString()
    Console.WriteLine("Last Name: " + e.Element("lastname").Value);
}
```

Comment: Thx you for your help, but I copy pasted your code and replaced mine with it, and I got the following error on "e.Element" in the Console.WriteLine statement : 'IEnumerable <XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Element' and no extension method 'Element' accepting a first argument of type ''IEnumerable <XElement>' could be found.

Comment: Ah I think I was missing a `.Elements()`, see the edit. (feal's answer helped)

Comment: this solution still does not compile

Comment: There's another error on the realTeam.Elements() part :P

Comment: I realized why, there could be multiple teams named "RealMadrid". I will edit my code.

Comment: I tried the new code you wrote and I got this error on `Console.WriteLine("First Name: " + e.Element("firstname").Value);` : System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'